# Should I add optional parameter to my function for test cases?

Tags: unit-testing, dart, flutter

I have the function below, I want to access the context globally and I don't know if it's a good idea, I'm getting the context from the Application, I have TestAppliction in the test environment and I don't have access to the Application class, so I decided to add an optional context parameter to my function.

```dart
String getErrorMessage(DioError error, {BuildContext context}) {
  String rawMessage = _getAnalyzedMessage(error);
  GlobalKey navKey = Application.navKey;

  if (navKey != null && navKey.currentContext != null)
    context = Application.navKey.currentContext;

  if (context != null)
    return AppLocalizations.of(context).translate(rawMessage);
  else
    return rawMessage;
}
```

Is this a good idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it the other way around. Pass the second argument always from outside - in both the tests and the real use case.

It doesn't have to be a second parameter of a static function though. You can promote it to an instance method and pass the context to constructor of such class, if that makes it easier to consume...

Answer (score 1):

By adding separate logic for your test case you are making it less representative of the code you are trying to test.

If `AppLocalizations.of(null)` returned an identity translator, then you could remove the final if statement.